# jni crash dvmAttachCurrentThread strlen

Tags: android, java-native-interface

My android app is crashed on line, the traces is as bellow:

```
backtrace:
#00 pc 00016f24 /system/lib/libc.so (strlen+72)
#01 pc 000542e5 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmGetThreadName(Thread*)+80)
#02 pc 00051a6f /system/lib/libdvm.so
#03 pc 00052011 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmLockObject+192)
#04 pc 0001e71c /system/lib/libdvm.so
#05 pc 0002bb68 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+180)
#06 pc 0005f7f1 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+272)
#07 pc 0005f81b /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
#08 pc 00052f39 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmAttachCurrentThread(JavaVMAttachArgs const*, bool)+296
```

ABI:armeabi-v7a

Android-Version:4.1.1

```
JNIEnv* getJNIEnv(jint& attached)
{ 
    JNIEnv *env = NULL;
    attached = gGlobalVM->GetEnv(&env, JNI_CURRENT_VERSION);
    if(attached == JNI_EDETACHED){
        if (gGlobalVM->AttachCurrentThread(&env, nullptr) < 0){
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    return env;
}
```

Comment: post your code in your question, not as a comment (and post a full code, not just two lines...)

Comment: code follows:  `
JNIEnv* getJNIEnv(jint& attached)
{
    JNIEnv *env = NULL;
    attached = gGlobalVM->GetEnv(&env, JNI_CURRENT_VERSION);
    switch (attached) {
    case JNI_OK:
        return env;
    case JNI_EDETACHED:
        if (gGlobalVM->AttachCurrentThread(&env, nullptr) < 0){
            LOGE("Failed to get the environment");
            return NULL;
        }
        else{
            return env;
        }
    case JNI_EVERSION:
        LOGE("JNI version not supported");
    default:
        LOGE("Failed to get the environment");
        return NULL;
    }
}`

Comment: edit your question, do not post your code as a comment

Comment: I post my new code now.  I try to copy from my workspace and paset, but paste fail.

Comment: i got same crash, do you know how to solve this